# Why is science fiction and fantasy referred to as "genre fiction", but other genres are not?

Tags: science-fiction-genre, fantasy-genre, genre

An oddity I have noticed in mainstream media and criticism is that science fiction and fantasy are referred to as "genre fiction" but other genres (comedy, romance, drama, etc) are not. All the online dictionaries I checked did not make this distinction, treating all genres equally, but the bias toward science fiction and fantasy is clearly present in mainstream media and criticism.

I have no idea why this is, though I suspect it is because the mainstream media and critics are generally derisive towards what they call "genre fiction". This too is something I find strange, as science fiction and fantasy are very vaguely defined *settings* in which one could have comedy, romance, drama, horror, mystery, innumerable other genres, innumerable sub-genres thereof, etc.

Comment: I thought romance was also considered "genre fiction"?

Comment: Lots of people split fiction  into two main categories; genre fiction and literary fiction with the former being the more commercial, type-based works. I don't see that many people referring to sci-fi as being the *only* genre fiction, just one category of it.

Comment: There are some properties that distinguish contemporary genre and literary fiction - such as contemporary genre being primarily plot-driven, whereas literary is primarily character-driven, the importance on the creative use of language, etc. It's not black and white, of course - but, generally speaking, belonging to the "genre" category is a matter of how heavily plot-driven the work is.

Comment: If you're asking what I think you are you may have more luck on the [Writing SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/).